# Using Get with a few symbols to continue work in a later session

Tags: streams

I have a notebook where I calculate integrals that take a long time to evaluate.

Let's say that I assign each evaluation to a symbol:

```
a1=some difficult integral
a2=some other difficult integral
```

In a later session I want to continue my calculations with those symbol `a1`, `a2` and more. So one way is to write into a file the values:

`Put[a1,a2,...,{filename}]`

But when I use Get in a later session, Mathematica only takes the first line of the file:

```
Get["filename"]
(*prints only the value of a1*)
```

So `a1=Get["filename"]` gives the value for `a1`, but how do I get the second line to be the value of `a2`?

The option of using DumpSave works fine but it creates a binary file and I prefer non-binary files. Is there a way to do that with using plain text streams?

Comment: How about exporting as an .m file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help of Get:

"reads in a file, evaluating each expression in it and returning the last one."

Therefore, to use Put/Get you would need to write the definitions, not only the values. To write the definition, you need "Save". Here is a simple example:

```
a1=1;
a2=2;
a3=3;
```

We save the definitions to a file:

```
filename= "d:/tmp/test.dat";
DeleteFile[filename] // Quiet; (*if the file exists, output would be appended*)
Save[filename,{a1,a2,a3}]
```

We now delete a1..a3:

```
Clear[a1,a2,a3]
```

Finally we read the saved definitions:

```
Get[filename];
```

Get would return only the last value: , but it nevertheless defines a1..a3.

We can now check the values of a1..a3:

```
a1
a2
a3
```

(* 1  2  3 *)

Finally the saved file looks like:

[image: ![enter image description here]